# Remote file access from PHP server side gives 301 instead of file, what to do?

Tags: php, http-status-code-301

EDIT: the answer is in the comments to the marked answer.

I am currently working with updating a few key components on a mobile web site. The site uses data from a different server to display student schedules. Recently this other site (over which I have zero control) was subject to a major overhaul and naturally I now have to update the mobile web site.

What I am trying to do is to access an iCal file and parse it. Since the site I am working on runs in an environment that does not have the curl-library nor have fopen wrappers properly set up I have resorted to the method described [here](http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/php-tutorial/reading-a-remote-file-using-php.aspx) (number 4, using a socket directly).

My current issue is that instead of getting the iCal-file I get a 301 error. However, if I attempt to access the same file (via the same URL) in a web browser it works just fine.

EDIT:
I added a bit of logging and here is what came out of it:

```
------------- 
Querying url:      
https://someUrl/schema/ri654Q055ZQZ60QbQ0ygnQ70cWny067Z0109Zx4h0Z7o525Y407Q.ics  
Response:   
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently  
Server: nginx/1.2.8  
Date: Sun, 11 Aug 2013 14:08:36 GMT  
Content-Type: text/html  
Content-Length: 184  
Connection: close  
Location:   
https://someUrl/schema/ri654Q055ZQZ60QbQ0ygnQ70cWny067Z0109Zx4h0Z7o525Y407Q.ics

<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.2.8</center>
</body>
</html>

Redirect url found: https://someUrl/schema/ri654Q055ZQZ60QbQ0ygnQ70cWny067Z0109Zx4h0Z7o525Y407Q.ics
```

The new location I am getting is identical to the original one.

This is the code used:

```
function getRemoteFile($url)
{

    error_log("------------- \r\nQuerying url: " . $url, 3, "error_log.log");
  // get the host name and url path
  $parsedUrl = parse_url($url);
  $host = $parsedUrl['host']; 
  if (isset($parsedUrl['path'])) {
     $path = $parsedUrl['path'];
  } else {
     // the url is pointing to the host like http://www.mysite.com
     $path = '/';
  }
  if (isset($parsedUrl['query'])) {
     $path .= '?' . $parsedUrl['query'];
  } 

  if (isset($parsedUrl['port'])) {
     $port = $parsedUrl['port'];
  } else {
     // most sites use port 80
     // but we want port 443 because we are using https
     error_log("Using port 443\r\n" . $url, 3, "error_log.log");
     $port = 443;
  }
  $timeout = 10;
  $response = '';
  // connect to the remote server 
  $fp = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout );
  if( !$fp ) { 
     echo "Cannot retrieve $url";
  } else {
    $payload = "GET $path HTTP/1.0\r\n" .
                "Host: $host\r\n" .
                "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.0.3) Gecko/20060426 Firefox/1.5.0.3\r\n" .
                "Accept: */*\r\n" .
                "Accept-Language: sv-SE,sv;q=0.8,en-us,en;q=0.3\r\n" .
                "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7\r\n" .
                "Referer: https://$host\r\n\r\n";
    error_log("\nPAYLOAD: " . $payload, 3, "error_log.log");
     // send the necessary headers to get the file 
     fputs($fp, $payload);
     // retrieve the response from the remote server 
     while ( $line = stream_socket_recvfrom( $fp, 4096 ) ) {
        $response .= $line;
     }
     fclose( $fp );
     // naively find location redirect
     $location_pos = strpos($response, "Location:");
     if($location_pos){
        $location_pos += 10;
        $new_url = substr($response, $location_pos, strpos($response, "\r\n\r\n") - $location_pos);
        error_log("\nRedirect url found: " . $new_url, 3, "error_log.log");
     }else{
        //log the response
        error_log($response, 3, "error_log.log");
     }


     // strip the headers
     $pos      = strpos($response, "\r\n\r\n");
     $response = substr($response, $pos + 4);
  }
  // return the file content 
  return $response;
}
```

Comment: if the redirect is identical to your request, it seems likely that the server is configured wrong. You should contact them. (but be careful that it isn't a `http` vs `https` or `www` vs `[no www]` difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[HTTP Response Code 301](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.2) is a permanent redirect, not an error.

Your code will have to follow that redirect in order to access the resource.

For example, http://google.com/ returns a 301 in order to redirect users to http://www.google.com/ instead.

```
$ curl -I http://google.com/
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.google.com/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Sun, 11 Aug 2013 01:25:34 GMT
Expires: Tue, 10 Sep 2013 01:25:34 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=2592000
Server: gws
Content-Length: 219
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic
```

You can see the 301 response on line 2, followed by the Location header which tells the web browser where to go instead.

What likely happened was that during this major overhaul, they moved the resource to another location. In order not to break any users bookmarks or calendar, they used a 301 redirect so that clients will automatically fetch the resource from the new location.

Comment: I found the location line, however it contains the same URL as I originally use to get the file. This is the response I am getting:

`HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently`  

`Server: nginx/1.2.9  
Date: Sun, 11 Aug 2013 00:59:51 GMT  
Content-Type: text/html  
Content-Length: 184  
Connection: close  
Location:    

https://***/schema/ri654Q055ZQZ60QbQ0ygnQ70cWny067Z0109Zx4h0Z7o525Y407Q.ics
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.2.9</center>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: @user1131180 and is what comes after the `Location:` exactly what you're fetching? This includes the https and if the redacted domain has a www in front of it or not. Take exactly what's after the Location and try to fetch that instead.

For example, if I fetch your URL over http, it will give me a 301 redirect to the https resource (a simple Google search revealed a paste bin you posted with the full URL).

Comment: No worries the url is public, was trying to make the comment look nicer but botched it completely. The new location given is identical to the initial one and the script gets stuck in a loop. I will update the question with the code I am using.

Comment: @user1131180 On the `$fp = fsocketopen` line, change the `fsocketopen` to read `$fp = fsockopen('ssl://'.$host, $port…`

When you are using fsocketopen to connect to HTTPS or a port that uses SSL, you need to put ssl:// in front of the hostname so that fsocketopen can handle the SSL handshakes.